# What are the differences between Hybrid Connection and the On-Premises Data Gateway?

Tags: azure, integration

What are the differences between Hybrid Connection and the On-Premises Data Gateway?

Initially my focus is on Azure App Services (Web Apps, Logic Apps, maybe API Apps) connecting to internal web services

I started checking out Hybrid Connections versus Service Bus Relay, but another member of the team mentioned the On-Premises Data Gateway which is coming from the [Microsoft business application platform](https://businessplatform.microsoft.com/en-us/), so Power BI, Microsoft Flow and Power Apps

So I'm now confused over the direction ... is the Gateway replacing Hybrid and Relay?

Comment: This is a very relevant question and so far the only thing I noticed is that Data gateway is definitely needed for MS client apps where you cannot provide any service account or where you need to connect to datasource using user identity (power apps,power bi, logic apps etc) but for webapps , webapis I think data gateway is not necessary as you can have a service account to connect to data source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure about this but it seems that On-Premises Data Gateway is a connection between On-Premise and servers (IaaS) in Azure. Hybrid Connection is used to connect On-Premise to e.g. Web Apps (PaaS) in Azure.

So I would say that at least one difference is whether On-Premise is connected to IaaS or PaaS.

My answer above is based on information in following links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway
https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/resources/videos/josh-twist-introduces-hybrid-connections

Comment: There seem to be three different "hybrid" options from Microsoft; Hybrid Connection Manager around App Service, On-Premise Data Gateway around Logic Apps and Data Management Gateway around Data Factory

Answer (score -1):

From an integration perspective, let's say you want to read some data from on-premises SQL server as a step in a logic app.
If you have either a Site-to-Site VPN or ExpressRoute providing connectivity between your on-premises network and Azure VNET, create an Azure ISE (Integration Services Environment) deployed to an Azure VNET. You will then be able to connect directly to the SQL server from your Logic App (since it is resolvable / contactable via DNS). Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment-overview
If you do not have this connectivity in place, you can install a Data Gateway component on-premises to present configured internal data sources to Azure using a persistent outbound connection (like app proxy). Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection
However, even if you do have network connectivity in place, in some scenarios (and from experiences) there may be a benefit in using the Data Gateway for it's caching capabilities (if applicable to the scenario). Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/gateway-onprem-sizing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).